# SQLite helper classes for each table issues

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using an SQLite db in my android application and I setup helper classes for each table in the db. There are many tables and these classes just handle all the crud methods for each table. I followed example #6 [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html.)

I'm having an issue when there are multiple instances of the helper classes instantiated. The database is only available when one helper class is instantiated at a time.

```
public class ProjectsHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    private String TABLE_NAME = "Projects";

    public ProjectsHelper(Context context){
        if(dbHelper == null){
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        }
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        try {
            if(!isOpen()){
                db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean isOpen(){
        return db != null && db.isOpen();
    }

    public void close() {
        if(isOpen()){
            dbHelper.close();
            db.close();
            dbHelper = null;
            db = null;
        }
    }

    public long insert(Project obj){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("ProjName", obj.getProjName().trim());
        if(!Utilities.empty(obj.getProjDesc())){
            values.put("ProjDesc", obj.getProjDesc().trim());
        }
        if(!Utilities.empty(obj.getProjNumber())){
            values.put("ProjNum", obj.getProjNumber().trim());
        }
        values.put("ServerID", obj.getServerID());
        values.put("GUID", obj.getGUID());
        values.put("ModDate", obj.getModDate());

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        return id;
    }
}


public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.siscoders.arscompnentinspector/databases/";

    public static String DB_NAME = "ARSInspection.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;

        try {
            createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {
            //openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }


    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Comment: Make ProjectsHelper as singleton

Comment: @RaghuRamiReddy how do I make a singleton when the class requires an argument with the context?

Comment: In your case multiple instances are creating for ProjectHelper. Its not the problem of supplying context in constructor. So modify the code as following and always supply getApplicationConntext() as context. ................... public static synchronized ProjectsHelper getInstance(Context context) {    
    if (sInstance == null) {
      sInstance = new ProjectsHelper(context);
    }
    return sInstance;
  }

Comment: Create one and only one DataBaseHelper instance and pass it as a parameter to respective table helpers constructors.